# How do I setup an ODBC connection to perform multiple querys(SQLExecDirect) in c++?

Tags: c++, sql, odbc

I have the following code (using ODBC to connect to an SQL database):
The connection is OK and also the first SQL_ExecuteQuery(), but the second and third SQL_ExecuteQuery() will return with an error (returncode -1 for SQLExecDirect).
I assume, that the "statement handle hstmt" will be overwritten after the first execution. But how can I avoid this? Thank you so much.

```
SQLHENV henv = SQL_NULL_HENV;
SQLHDBC hdbc = SQL_NULL_HDBC;
SQLHDBC hstmt= SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
SQLRETURN retcode = SQL_SUCCESS;

//Connect function
int SQL_Connect()
{
SQLWCHAR OutConnStr[255];
SQLSMALLINT OutConnStrLen;

// Allocate environment handle
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);

// Set the ODBC version environment attribute
if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
{
    retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0); 

    // Allocate connection handle
    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc); 

        // Set login timeout to 5 seconds
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) 
        {
            SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

            retcode = SQLDriverConnect( hdbc,
                                        NULL,
                                        #ifdef IPC
                                            (SQLWCHAR *)L"DSN=TEST;Description=ODK;UID=FFF;PWD=XXX;Trusted_Connection=No;DATABASE=DDD;",
                                        #else
                                            (SQLWCHAR *)L"DSN=ODKSQL64;Description=ODK;UID=auto;PWD=Visu_KDbos;Trusted_Connection=No;DATABASE=Giesserei_BKO;",
                                        #endif
                                        SQL_NTS,
                                        OutConnStr,
                                        255, 
                                        &OutConnStrLen,
                                        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT); 

            // Allocate statement handle
            if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
            {
                retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt); 

                cout<<"Verbindung OK"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
 return retcode;
}

//Disonnect function
int SQL_Disconnect ()
{
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt );
SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);

return 1;
}

//Query function
int SQL_ExecuteQuery()
{
short rc;
char material[50];
SQLINTEGER strlenmaterial;

//prepare query
std::wstring SQL_Statement = L"SELECT blablabla";

rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, const_cast<SQLWCHAR*>(SQL_Statement.c_str()), SQL_NTS);

if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, &material, (SQLINTEGER) sizeof(material), &strlenmaterial);
        while (1) {
            rc = SQLFetch(hstmt);
            if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                rc = 1;
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //no data found
        rc = 3;
    }

return rc;
}


int main()
{
short rc;

rc = SQL_Connect();

rc = SQL_ExecuteQuery();
rc = SQL_ExecuteQuery();
rc = SQL_ExecuteQuery();

rc = SQL_Disconnect();


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use a HSTMT handle, but before running a new query, you need to close the pending cursor. As you are binding the columns using `SQLBindCol`, you also need to unbind the columns, before binding them again.

In your `SQL_ExecuteQuery()`, before returning from the function call:

```
SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_UNBIND)
SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE)
```

Now you are ready to execute another query, bind again and fetch the result.

Note that you could also change the logic of your program, and bind only once, and then skip the unbind-step: If you know that you are always interested in the result of the same column, you could bind the column before executing the query. You can then execute the query, read the result, call `SQLFreeStmt` with the `SQL_CLOSE` option and start over with executing the query.

See here for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlfreestmt-function

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @Osti: Welcome. Can you accept it as answer then, to make it clear it solved your problem?.